# AADB2C Sign In with Apple and use Apple Private Email Relay Service

Tags: ios, azure-ad-b2c

This [document](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) states:

> Note: even if you include the name or email scopes, nether will not be included as claims in the token which Azure AD B2C receives from Apple. Apple provides these values in a non-standard way as part of the authorization response payload. Azure AD B2C will not be able to read these values and you should collect them from the user separately if needed.

Is this information still up to date? (Document seems to be older than 1 year). Are there any plans to facilitate this?

Does this actually mean that it is not possible to use [Apples Private Email Relay Service](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/?lang=en#/devf822fb8fc) in conjunction with AADB2C or is there an other way to contact users using [Sign In with Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210318) through email? (I'm aware that I can query the email from the user with a simple text field as a last resort.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless Apple provide these values in the standard way (e.g OIDC) the guidance is still correct.

AFAIK you should receive an email address back from Apple --  it will be the actual email of the user if they choose to share it with the app, otherwise it will be the one with the relay service address.

Comment: So far I do not see a email address in the AD after successfull registration with Apple ID, but I run through the user flow only in the web browser and not in the iOS App itself.

Comment: For more clear understanding did you created the user in the Azure AD B2C with the AppleID and when you run the userflow  you are not able to receive the Email claim..?